# How to update a value in a Cache withour removal?

Tags: caching, guava

I want to update a value in a non-loading cache:

```
Cache<String, Session> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess( 30l, TimeUnit.MINUTES ).removalListener( removalListener ).build()

cache.put id, s
```

or

```
cache.asMap().put id, s
```

in both cases the removalListener get's called and this is what I want to avoid.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to prevent a `RemovalListener` from being called when you replace an element. As [the documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/RemovalListener.html) says (emphasis added):

> The removal resulting in notification could have occured to an entry being **manually removed or replaced**, or due to eviction resulting from timed expiration, exceeding a maximum size, or garbage collection.

However, you can examine the `cause` field of the `RemovalNotification` object. If the cause is `REPLACED`, then the entry was removed as a result of a call to `put`, `replace` or `refresh`.